# Heroku - custom domain DNS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, heroku, dns

I am a complete newbie when it comes to redirecting etc.

I bought a domain (mydomain.co) and I have a heroku app (mydomain.herokuapp.com) (upgrading to paid in the upcoming month). What I want to do is to be able to access the heroku app after entering the domain url and stay o this domain, and not be redirected to mydomain.herokuapp.com.

My settings for the domain look like this (I translated it myself, so there may be some mistakes):

[image]
[image]

With this settings, I can access my app but it is displayed in a frame, what's more - some of the pages do not work.

What I want to do is to be able to type mydomain.co and display mydomain.herokuapp.com but as regular site, and not inside a frame. What options should I choose?

Another thing is - will I be able to use the domain (which I paid for) and do the redirect if I do not buy a hosting from the company?

PS I added custom domains to my herokuapp and read their [guide], but I still do not understand.[3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

Here are also my domain records - I believe it has something to do with this, but it so hard to test it as those DNS changes take some time.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove your redirection.  You also need to put a CNAME on `mydomain.co` with value `mydomain.herokuapp.com`.

Comment: If you are not allowed to make a Cname of the mydomain.co then ypu have to update the A record with the correct ip address for yor site, also if you have hostheaders on the site, then you will need to add the "mydomain.co" in the hostheaders for the site

Comment: After entering `mydomain.co` in the element name, `mydomain.herokuapp.com` insinde the value and setting record type to CNAME I see an error saying  "You can't create record for existing subdomain" and "Record type can be set to CNAME only for hosts in domain".  Based on the comment for the answer - should I remove the `domain_ip_address` and enter `mydomain.herokuapp.com` or should I find the IP addres for my app?

Comment: Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com
Address:  23.23.118.248
Aliases:  mydomain.herokuapp.com

set 23.23.118.248 instead of "domain_ip_address"

Comment: You were not able to search for it as I did not give you neither IP or address, and mydomain.co etc. is just for example. If I did not understand your comment then sorry :( Anyway, based on this I should get the IP for mydomain.herokuapp.com and write it inside A record type value, or will the mydomain.herokuapp.com be enough?

Comment: You will need to enter a IP-Address in the A Record

Comment: So this won't be possible, as heroku apps do not have a stable IP address. Any ideas why I am not able to set the CNAME? Should I contact the company I bought a domain from to set it or is there another way?

Comment: it is common that DNS servers do require an A record for the root domain. <br /> You could try find a free dns server that allows a CNAME on your root. <br /> Another way is to use a subdomain on mydomain.co

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126731/discussion-between-ancinek-and-lars-skogshus).